# Why are "Egyptian God" cards so significant?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Recently, I was browsing through the questions on B&CG SE  (particularly in the [yu-gi-oh] tag) and I see quite a bit of Egyptian God. I was duelling someone from my school, and he said

> "Egyptian God Cards cannot be targeted by any card effect or be destroyed by battle"!

Obviously we dismissed this as another pathetic blurt of words from him, because he makes up so many rules, and cheats,so we told him unless it's on the rule book or the card, it's false, but he dismissed it, so I forfeited in order to maintain my sanity, but this in particular made me wonder:

**What's so special about the Egyptian God Cards? Why are these cards more significant than other cards?**

I understand that in Yugi's (?) season of the anime l, the Egyptian Gods were established (?). They were a group of really powerful monsters, that could destroy the world if control were lost over them in a duel.

So, does what this person from my school said have any origins from the anime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They were represented in the anime as being incredibly powerful, and you never saw them defeated by traditional means. In the card game they act as normal cards and have no special "you can't destroy me or target me" abilities I'm aware of (I'll admit it's been a while since I played Yu-Gi-Oh as I moved over to Magic, but I played quite a bit)

Your friend sounds like he's putting a more flavourful edge to things as it makes sense when you look at the anime, but it's not how the game actually works.

Also, if your friend continues to make up rules and cheat, I'd look to find a way to "punish" him in order to correct his behaviour. Stop playing games with him when he does it for example. If he really wants to play the game he'll learn to play correctly if you just show him that cheating doesn't pay off.

Comment: Well yes, thanks! I've stopped playing with cheats altogether now (meaning that I've stopped playing with most people) but it's worth it, for I get time, satisfaction (sometimes off losing), and other benefits as well you don't get from playing with cheats.

Comment: If you want to play a game where you get a lot less cheats, try Magic, it's (in my opinion) a better game and the community is generally pretty welcoming and helpful. I am a little biased as I play a LOT of Magic

Answer (score -2):

If you have seen yugioh before god cards can be prevented from being summoned if you have the exchange card you can take that go card you can also make sure the don't have three tributes to sacrifice in order to summon a god card i have all three gods in my deck including the three blue eyes white dragons and blue eyes ultimate dragon but watch out for ra's abilates if he is put in the graveyard you can use monster reborn to bring   him back for one turn if you tribute 1000 life point's you can wipe out all your opponents monsters then he returns to the graveyard there is also the god pheonix

Comment: Welcome to board and card games. Can you please edit your answer and add some punctuation. It is hard to read right now.